# integrate asp.net services without api or web service call

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, integration

how do I send a request to a page that doesn't offer an API or web serviece like this one for example

http://arcgis.dmgov.org/extmapcenter/addresslookup.aspx

from inside my asp.net webapplication.

The problem is, how will I pass the information in my request. in the case above for example, I need to pass the address.

Comment: r u caching response from this URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each browser has a set of developer tools for monitoring HTTP requests. In Chrome you can hit ctrl+shift j, go to Network, and examine the HTTP request used when you hit the submit button on that page. Most often sending data to the server will use an HTTP POST which that site does. What is important is to see the variables they use to send the POST data. That site sends the following

```
ctl00$CPH4contentWindow$txtAddress:111 Street Name
```

With a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

You can try to mimic this by sending your own HTTP request with that information.

**Client**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Address/111%20Street%20Name',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (result) {
        // do something with result
    }
});
```

---

**Controller**

```
public class AddressController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(string address)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.AddHeader("content-type", "application/www-form-urlencoded");
        string response = client.UploadString("http://arcgis.dmgov.org/extmapcenter/addresslookup.aspx", "ctl00$CPH4contentWindow$txtAddress=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(address));
        return response;
    }
}
```

If you don't need it to be sent asynchronously with ajax you can just put the logic for the Controller into your ASP.NET code behind.

Comment: This uses JQuery. By the way it will only work if the page making the request is on the same domain - same origin policy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. so in this case they both should be on http://arcgis.dmgov.org

Comment: Oh, right. Well then he could just relay the request from his own Web Api Controller and return the result. I'll update the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web browser addons like firebug for firefox to see what requests that page is making. For your sample case it is making a request to

http://arcgis.dmgov.org/extmapcenter/AutoComplete.asmx/GetLocAddressList
with 
prefixText to "textInsindeTextbox"

make this request from your application. But that webservice may not allow you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Issue a HTTP GET request: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023

or use IFRAME HTML tag if you want it on the client side.

Comment: I am afraid I did not make my self clear. how do I pass information in my request. like the address to the link I have included above.